# Inputting data into "R Commander"

Tags: r, dataset, r-commander

I installed R Commander and have no success in inputting a data set. I have read online how to do it, but it does not seem to work. Here are the steps I have taken.

1. Open R.
2. Open *R Commander*
3. Click on "Data" then "New data set" and enter "test" as the name for the data set, click *OK*
4. In the *Data Editor,* double-click on *var1* and changed it to "a" (Type: Numeric)
5. Enter numbers into the first column
6. In the "Data Editor" window, click "File" then "Close"

When I click this, however, another "Data Editor" window open. After closing this, a window appears called "Select Data Set." I click "test" and in the Messages section of R Commander it says *NOTE: The dataset has 0 rows and 0 columns*

Is there a step I am missing?

Thanks in advance for replies. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not a direct answer to your question, but a possible workaround : I don't really know about R Commander, but in general it is easier to input your data in an external application such as Excel or OpenOffice Calc, save them to a CSV file and then import this file into R.

The R Commander menu *Data* > *Import data* should allow you to import many different formats quite easily.

One of the advantages is that external applications often provide easier ways to input data. And by the way you also learn how to import data into R, which should be useful if you decide to continue using it.